# Select dropdown with the Style of Multiple select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i make the normal select dropdown

```
<select>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
</select>
```

looks exactly like

```
<select name="" id="" multiple>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
</select>
```

But with the ability to only click one option, And clicking any other option changes the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select size="5">
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
  <option value="">OPTION</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That it?  I wasted like 4 hours learning JavaScript because i thought it is the solution and THAT IT? Really thank you, You solved a real problem for me.

Comment: @Calibur Victorious it's does worth a lot to learn js for 4 hours : ) You can use js to reset the size value considering it your options are dynamic. Thus format will be always up to date.